# how return multiple values from thread and how handle this value

Tags: java, multithreading, return-value

I am new to Java window applications.  I need to make a Java tool that runs a script.  The script is run like `- .txt file` and gives the following output:

```
line 1   
line 2  
line 3
and so on....
```

I need the Java program to do the following steps:

1. check each line syntax is correct or not
2. if line is correct , make a byte[] with this line
3. process byte[] array

I want to use thread concpt here.  I want that child thread handle 1 and 2 processes and return a `byte[]` to main thread.  The main program would then process this byte array.

I am able to use thread, but have a problem with return values.  How does a thread return `byte[]` for each line to main thread?  How does the main thread receive this `byte[]` array in syncronized manner?

Comment: Will there be only one text file ?

Comment: yes there are only one text file with no of line, each line represent a command , i need to extract it if it is well written

Comment: Then accessing one file by multiple threads will be not a good multi threaded solution.

Comment: I just edited your question.  Hope I didn't change the meaning.  It was almost unreadable before.

Comment: Note that parsing a command line takes no time at all on modern computers. So in practice nobody would ever create such a scheme, at least not for the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to return values from a thread is to use the `ExecutorService` and the `Future` class.  You can submit as many jobs as you want into the thread-pool.  You can also add more threads or fork a thread per job.  See the other methods in `Executors`.

For example:

```
// create a thread pool
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
// submit a job to the thread pool maybe with the script name to run
Future<byte[]> future1 = threadPool.submit(new MyCallable("scriptFile1.txt"));
// waits for the task to finish, get the result from the job, this may throw
byte[] result = future1.get();

public class MyCallable implements Callable<byte[]> {
    private String fileName;
    public MyCallable(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
    public byte[] call() {
        // run the script
        // process the results into the byte array
        return someByteArray;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your time gray... it looks tough.... i am going to try this. and i hope ........

Comment: in normal thread, i make a object of thread class, and call obj.start() on a button click or from anywhere. you mean to say i should use public class MyCallable implements Callable<byte[]> instead of public class mythread extend Thread { } right? one thing is more- if my file contain 10 line means i need to return 10 byte[] one by one, but it seems it will be return only once. give me some hint, how i can process line one by one and return byte[] for each line, I want to implement like- as sooon thread return a value , instantly some line of code execute and use return value

Comment: Yes the `ExecutorService` handles the threads for you.  All you need is a `Callable`.

Comment: You can only return one value from a `Future`.  It could be a `List<byte[]>`.  If you want the threads to communicate while processing then the processing thread can add a `byte[]` to a `BlockingQueue` instead of the `Future`.

Comment: it is really some real concept and i am a beginner , i need to spend my time with this , but unfortunately i need to do my assignment, so can you code for me.... a simple scenario is- file.txt contain 5 lines , each line contain a name, i need to print it in console, i want to pass the file path to thread, thread read line by (line = readline() !=null) and send to the main thread , then main thread print it in console, what i require is "SYNCHRONIZATION" - send one line by thread , a code print it in cosole by System.out.println(line);

Comment: if you think this is a genuine question, give me some code to better understand, if you dont, avoid it, i will try by my own,,,,,anyways thanks for you attention

Comment: Sorry dude.  Can't do it for you.  Best of luck.